Why my bash script works in the terminal but fails in a script with a function involved and ssh call?
I have
#!/bin/bash

function installed (){
ssh "secondnode" 'echo $(dpkg-query -W ${1} 2>&1|awk '\''{if ($0 ~ /no packages/) {print "not installed"} else {print "installed"}}'\'')')
}
VAR1=$(installed "somepackage")
echo $VAR1

The output is correct for the first run. To get a correct output for a new run I need to modify the function command, for instance add "${1}" and save.
However the same line of myfunction in the terminal (not a script) runs perfectly, of course, replacing ${1} with "somepackage".  It seems like the previous output is stored somewhere and never changed...
On the other hand, how can I improve my code with a function to know if a package is installed or not in a remote node? Seems like mine doesn't work properly.

echo $(cmd)? Just cmd

ssh line works perfectly in the terminal with $(cmd). it just fails in a script with a function and ${1}

I got the issue, ${1} is within a single quote, I shoudl remove it from single quote to make it work

Verbal descriptions of prroblems are often ambiguous or just generally hard to understand. lease read  the section How to turn a bad script into a good question (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash) and try to reconstruct your problem with the smallest amount of code that fails. Set up the example so it will show output (you have done this), but also show your current erroneous output. Also, I agree with MarkP, when do you use myfunction() ? Good luck.

Your script does not really make sense. You define a function named 'myfunction', but you never call it. Instead you call a program named installed.

You are right. I fixed the typo. the function is function installed (){...}

Just by adding '' to ${1} fixes the problem, so the line is ssh "secondnode" 'echo $(dpkg-query -W '${1}' 2>&1|awk '\''{if ($0 ~ /no packages/) {print "not installed"} else {print "installed"}}'\'')')  however, is much easier to avoid awk to simplify it

Your edit to add the function keyword was not an improvement. It basically adds no value, and reduces the portability of code which could otherwise work in shells which do not use this essentially superfluous Bash-only keyword.

The single quotes in your attempt prevent $1 from being expanded at all.
Your code has a number of other beginner problems; probably run it through https://shellcheck.net/ to get diagnostics.
Here is an attempt to refactor it.
#!/bin/sh

installed (){
    ssh "secondnode" dpkg-query -W "'${1}'" 2>&1 |
    awk '/no packages/ {print "not installed"; exit 1}
        {print "installed"; exit 0}'
}
installed "somepackage"

The changes include

Remove the function keyword. This is an unnecessary wart which Bash has retained for backwards compatibility, but it provides no value here.
Since the script then no longer uses any Bash-only features, change the shebang to #!/bin/sh
Don't run Awk remotely. Only run the dpkg command remotely (and avoid the useless echo with backticks)

The curious quoting around $1 uses double quotes around the value to prevent the local shell from splitting it, and single quotes to prevent the remote shell from performing any modifications on the resulting value. This is still brittle! In particular, if the value could contain a single quotes, this is insufficient.


Add an exit status to the Awk command line so that you can use the function for testing programmatically whether a package is installed. Ideally, the diagnostic output should be to standard error, or removed from the script entirely.
Don't capture the result just so you can immediately echo it when calling the function, either. (And if you do, quote the argument to echo, and don't use uppercase for your private variables.)

Here is another refactoring which removes the diagnostics from the Awk script, relying instead on the caller to decide whether or not to print a diagnostic. Actually, since the script is now so simple, I switched to grep instead. The ! inverts the exit code from the pipeline (so if grep succeeds, the pipeline fails, and vice versa.)
#!/bin/sh

installed (){
    ! ssh "secondnode" dpkg-query -W "'${1}'" 2>&1 |
      grep -Fq 'no packages'
}
installed "somepackage" && echo "installed" >&2 || echo "not installed" >&2


awk '/no packages/{f=1; exit} END{print (f ? "not " : "") "installed"; exit f}' would eliminate the duplicate code FWIW. Usually tools that search for anything (e.g. if you were using grep 'no packages' instead of awk '/no packages/' for this) exit with success (0) if that thing is found, not failure (1), and so then exit f would be exit !f (but I understand that then the shell function would need to negate it again, thereby introducing a double negative, so maybe having awk flip the usual exit status as you're doing is better in this case, idk).

You should be capturing the $1 right away and then use the function call to send the input to the "$1" in the function.
#!/bin/bash

input="$1"

myfunction() {
    local package_status=$(ssh secondnode "dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' $input 2>/dev/null")
    if [[ $package_status == "install ok installed" ]]; then
        echo "Installed."
        exit 0
    fi
}

myfunction

echo "Not found."
exit 1

Use: ./script.sh entry

With your method you don't need myfunction "$input", just calling myfunction is enough

On the other hand, having a global variable outside the function which controls its behavior sort of ruins the whole point of putting the logic in a function.

How so?  I used the function because the OP has, and it's not hurting anything.  It also provided a clear example of how positional parameters work.

Global variables are universally a bad idea, for extremely well-documented reason. The function's argument should be an explicit parameter, like the OP attempted. In other words, what @Fravadona pointed out can be solved two ways, but their comment implies keeping the global variable, which is obviously the worse solution.

@tripleee I just pointed-out the illogical use of an argument when calling my_function; I didn't want to dabble more in it as the answer selling point is to "capture $1 right away"

It seems you have some issues with special characters and variable substitutions. I have found that it often makes things easier when you break long one-liners into multiple steps.
In Bash (and other shell languages), single quotes behave differently from double quotes.
When having trouble with running non-trivial commands over ssh, it is a good idea to "dry-run" your code, i.e. echo the ssh command instead of running it to see what is actually being run. Syntax highlighting and a good linter helps too.
Here is a fixed version of your function. Take a good look at how the quotes are placed.
#!/bin/bash

function installed (){
    query="dpkg-query -W ${1} 2>&1"
    awkCmd="awk '{if (\$0 ~ /no packages/) {print \"not installed\"} else {print \"installed\"}}'"
    cmd="$query | $awkCmd"
    ssh "secondnode" "$cmd"
}

installed "somepackage"


Don't put commands in variables. In this particular case, it prevents you from even being able to quote "$1" properly. See also When to wrap quotes around a shell variable

The command argument in ssh is quite literally a string of text that represents the command to be run on the remote machine -- similar to eval. The problem then is to construct the correct string. I believe string-valued variables are quite alright for that purpose. Also, what do you mean by "quoting $1 properly"? Expansion at that point is intended. If quotes were needed around the package name, one could write "dpkg-query -W \"${1}\" 2>&1".

That would quote it from the remote shell, yes, but would still confusingly break if the value contained double quotes.
